# Join a DataFrame in another DataFrame's nested element

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have the below 2 DataFrame schemas. Inside `USER_INFO` `modules` is an array, `content` is an array nested inside `modules`. I want to join/attach some additional data (`METADATA`) to each `content` element, such that

```
USER_INFO.modules.content.id = METADATA.cust_id
```

What would be a solution?

```
USER_INFO

root
 |-- userId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- modules: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- content: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- distance: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- impressionId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)


 METADATA

 root
 |-- cust_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- image_url: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: What should happen if modules has multiple content id's and only one of them matches?

Comment: No join then. But normally all content.id-s have a pair. All have METADATA.

Comment: Additionally, I would like to make a map out of METADATA, having cust_id as the key and the value will be a struct holding image_url and additional fields, which I have not posted here for now.

Comment: Can you add an example of some sample USER_INFO and METADATA inputs and the desired output for clarity?